How to receive DeviceEvent with winit when application not focused?
I am newer to rust winit. I can receive DeviceEvent like MouseEvent when my application is focused. But if I click another app, my application will go to the backend and it can't receive DeviceEvent. How to let my application receive DeceiveEvent even if it is not focused? I am on Windows platform.

I don't think winit has support for that. Regular input methods only work when the application is focused. If you want to listen to global actions, on Windows you can use hooks. A simple search reveals willhook.

thx so much, I'll try it.
